# can I perform 3 row operation at the same time in a 3 by 3 determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra

I mean is it necessary to keep one row unchanged. r1'=r1+r3 r2'=r2-r3 r3'=r3+r2. I did these operations and the value of determinant is unchanged.is this a valid operation.

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: why can you explain?

Comment: Try an easy-to-calculate example, if your conjecture is true for at least 5 examples, try reformatting your question with $\LaTeX$.

Comment: in n by n determinant row / coloum operations are preformed keeping one row unchanged?why is that necessary.I mean..we can change it also

Answer (score 2):

You can demonstrate whether this particular operation is allowed by doing it as four operations in series.
$$r1'=r1+r3\\r2'=r2-r3\\r3'=2r3\\r3''=r3'+r2'=2r3+r2-r3=r3+r2$$
It should have doubled the determinant because of the third line.  Maybe you incorporated the change in $r2$ before doing the change in $r3$, so $r3'=r3+r2'=r2$.  That would be allowable.

If I do your operation to the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix I get $$\left| \begin {pmatrix} 1&0&1\\ 0&1&-1\\ 0&1&1 \end {pmatrix}\right|=2$$

Comment: is it mandatory to keep one row unchanged while changing the others?

Comment: why you write in third line r3'=2r3?

Comment: I had to do that to get $r3''$ to come out right as the sum of the original $r2$ and $r3$  If you look at my addition you see what happens to the identity by my understanding of what you did.  The determinant does double.  It is not mandatory to keep one row the same, the point is that we have proven that you can add a constant times one row to any other row and not change the determinant.  If we do one step at a time we know we will not change the determinant.  One could prove more theorems about row operations that do not change the determinant and use those but they are not standard.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in any determinant is to modify *one* row by adding a multiple of another row to it, and keep *all* the other rows unchanged. This doesn't change the value of the determinant.

By doing this repeatedly, you can make modifications which may amount to doing several row operations at once, but unless you are very careful, it's easy to make mistakes if you try to do several things at once. 
For example, you could do your first two operations at once, but doing the second and the third operation simultaneously is incorrect (it will double the value of the determinant).

So it's better to play it safe and stick to the basic operation described in the first paragraph.

Comment: @MaxPayane: I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: just tell me why one row or coloum has to remain unchanged while performing row /coloum operations?

Comment: In the basic step, not just **one** but **all but one** column must remain unchanged. However, you could do $r_1'=r_1+c_1 r_n$ and then in the next step $r_2'=r_2+c_2 r_n$, and so on until you have done $r_{n-1}'=r_{n-1}+c_{n-1}r_n$. All these operations can be done “in parallel”, and they leave $r_n$ unchanged. Now if you want to change $r_n$ next, you will add a multiple of some *already modified* $r_k'$ (not the original $r_k$): $r_n'' = r_n + d r_k' = r_n + d (r_k + c_k r_n) = (1+d c_k) r_n+d r_k$, and this is not an operation which just adds something to $r_n$, it's more complex.

Comment: but what about we operate all this operation at  the same time in such a way that it remains the orginal one.in this way we wont add anything in n th row.I mean we can use rk not the rk' if we operate simultaneously.

Comment: what's the problem with operating simultaneously in such a way that does not change orginal determinants value?

Comment: Well, as long as you know exactly what you're doing, so that you don't change the determinant's value, there's of course no problem! The problem is that it's quite easy to *accidentally* change the value if you're not very careful (as all the other answers also try to illustrate by examples!).

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing a row operation on a matrix determinant, what essentially you are doing is subtracting a zero determinant matrix from the original matrix. For eg:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\\ \end{vmatrix}
$$
changed to 
$$
\begin{vmatrix}a-lc&b-ld\\c&d\\ \end{vmatrix}
$$
This is subtracting the determinant
$$
-l\begin{vmatrix}c&d\\c&d\\ \end{vmatrix}
$$
which is zero from the original determinant (Note that this is determinant addition and not matrix addition).

Now when you want to do two row operations simultaneously, what you will do is,

$$
\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\\ \end{vmatrix}
-l\begin{vmatrix}c&d\\a&b\\ \end{vmatrix}
$$
**The determinant on the right is NOT zero. So you cannot add this to original determinant without changing its value.**

Take a simple 2x2 example $|I|  = 1$.
$$
\begin{vmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\ \end{vmatrix} = 1
$$
Now adding row1 to row2 and row2 to row1 simultaneously, it becomes
$$
\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\1&1\\ \end{vmatrix} = 0
$$
whose determinant is $0$.

This will translate easily to 3x3 dimensions, when applied the above rule.

Comment: can you please give a general rule of this row coloum operation. not  statement like most of the books.rather including how many combination of operation can be performed in n by n matrix.

Comment: r1'=r1+r3,r2'= r2+r3,r3'=r3+r2.if I do this operations and when we seperate the determinant into two, in second one we will have two same rows r3 and the determinanat will be zero.so how your rule works in this case?

Comment: Suppose 1st operation is involving r1, r2 and r3. Then your second operation must not involve these rows for the determinant to remain same. And similarly, your 3rd operation must not involve the rows involved in operation 1 and 2 and so on.

Note that this is only a rule of thumb and strictly speaking you should only perform one operation at a time for accurate results.

Comment: In some cases, you may get correct answer because of the algebraic nature of the operations while doing multiple operations simultaneously, but it is wrong and conceptually wrong.

Comment: why are you saying it conceptually wrong..isn't it a much more general way to state that one can take any linear combinations of other rows and operate it with any rows in such a way that the orginal determinant remain unchanged.

Comment: What I meant by conceptually wrong is that, your first operation can involve linear combinations of so many rows, and if even if your second operation involves a single row which was involved in the first operation, the determinant will change. So its better to perform one operation at a time. I shouldn't have used "conceptually", rather I should have said that you can formulate this behaviour of simultaneous operations

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of how performing row operations in parallel (instead of sequentially) can change the determinant.

$r_1' = r_1 + r_2$ and $r_2' = r_1+r_2$ are both valid row operations. But if we perform them at the same time then we have $r_1'=r_2'=r_1+r_2$. So we have made the first and second rows of the matrix equal - which means the determinant of the matrix has become $0$.

Comment: but what about higher order determinants.r1'=r1+r3,r2'= r2+r3,r3'=r3+r2.if I do this operations and when we seperate the determinant into two, in second one we will have two same rows r3 and the determinanat will be zero.simultaneously operating  having no change. what about this?

Comment: @MaxPayane: If you do this, the new determinant (with rows r1', r2', r3') will always be **zero**, since the rows r2' and r3' are equal. So if the determinant that you started with (with rows r1, r2, r3) was **nonzero**, then you have obviously **changed** its value! Which shows that this is **not** a valid operation to do if you want to guarantee that the determinant is unchanged. I don't understand what you mean by separating the determinant into two?

Comment: by it  i mean determinants property of writing one into two if one row is linear combination of other rows

Comment: lets take 3 by 3 determinant. why is only two row operation is valid for it.?why it is mandatory  to keep one row unchanged